# Как взять элементы списка попарно?

Tags: python, list, for

У меня есть список из координат [0, 1, 2, 3, 1], как мне взять элементы из списка и попарно иx присвоить x и y?
Чтобы в первом шаге x == 0, y == 1, потом x == 1, y == 2 и так далее.
Какие методы использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через индексы:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 1]

for i in range(len(a) - 1):
    x, y = a[i], a[i + 1]
    print(x, y)
```

Результат:

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a=[0, 1, 2, 3, 1]
for x,y in zip(a[:],a[1:]):
    print(x,y)

0 1
1 2
2 3
3 1
```

Stanislav Volodarskiy посоветовал не использовать не нужный срез в цикле т.е.

```
for x,y in zip(a,a[1:]):
```

чтобы не разбазаривать память.

Comment: Зачем `a[:]`?..

Comment: Чтобы было наглядно, первую часть пары-берем от 0, вторую часть пары от 1.

Comment: Так у вас тройная память. Могла бы быть двойная.

Comment: я в процессе изучения, с удовольствием почитал бы про Ваше замечание.

Comment: Тут почти ничего не надо читать. Нотация `a[:]`, `a[1:]` и любая `a[...:...]` делает копию куска исходного списка. Если у вас был список из миллиона элементов, вы изготовите его копии из миллиона и из *999999* элементов. Всего вы займёте утроенную память по сравнению с исходным списком.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то такое без дополнительных копирований:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 1]
it = iter(a)
next(it, None)
for x, y in zip(a, it):
    print(x, y)
```

Следующий код выдаёт пары вообще на любом [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable):

```
import itertools


def pairs(seq):
    it1, it2 = itertools.tee(seq)
    next(it2, None)
    return zip(it1, it2)
```